# How can I get pending transaction of contract address using web3.py?

Tags: transactions, web3.py, events, python, pending-transactions

I want to get pending transaction of a contract address, I have tried many ways but didn't work

method 1: this seems to be good at sorting pending transaction but I can't  get any transaction from my address, I don't know why. Please help me

```
def main():
    block_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending') 
    log_loop(block_filter, 0)

def log_loop(block_filter, poll_interval):
    while True: 
        for event in block_filter.get_new_entries():
            if web3.eth.getTransaction(event)['to'] == my contract:
                print(event)
```

method 2: this help me to get transaction from my address but all transaction it get is comfirmed, not pending

```
def main():
    block_filter = web3.eth.filter({'fromBlock':'pending','toBlock':'pending', 'address':contract_address}) #this is not working, return nothing

    #block_filter = web3.eth.filter({'fromBlock':0,'toBlock':'pending', 'address':contract_address}) #return confirmed transaction, not pending

    #block_filter = web3.eth.filter({'fromBlock':'pending','toBlock':'latest', 'address':contract_address}) #return confirmed transaction, not pending

    #block_filter = web3.eth.filter({'fromBlock':'latest','toBlock':'pending', 'address':contract_address}) #return error from > to

    #block_filter = web3.eth.filter({'address':contract_address}) #return confirmed transaction, not pending
    log_loop(block_filter, 0)

def log_loop(block_filter, poll_interval):
    while True: 
        for event in block_filter.get_new_entries():
            print(event)
```